# Driver CDs to USB

Tags: usb, netbook

I have a netbook that doesn't have optical media. I want to install my wireless adapter drivers, but they're on CD and the link on OEM site is broke.

Is there a program (I've tried drag & drop from CD/content to USB, but it didn't work) that can 'put' this CD onto USB?

Could the same thing (CD to USB) be done for something like a game or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

you don't need any software for this. just copy the content of the CD onto a USB dtick/SDHC card.

then run the installer or extract the driver and install it manually via the device manager.

if you want to use a recorded ISO of the CD, you can mount it with **[WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/)** on your netbook.

Answer (score 1):

It "should" work by doing what you said (copying the files over and running the installer), but if it doesn't you can make an image (ISO) out of the CD using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) and then "mount" the image as if the CD were in a drive.

Is this Linux or Windows? the procedure to mount the CD is different in both.

And yes, this should work with other CD-based applications, although most recent games will have copy protection schemes that are designed to make this process fail.